# Prove by induction the derivative of $h(x)=x^n$

Tags: calculus, induction

Prove by induction that if $h(x) = x^n, n \in N, n > 0 $ then $h'(x) = nx^{n−-1}.$
You may only assume that if $f(x) = x$ then $f'(x) = 1$, that if f and g are differentiable then $(f + g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x)$ and that $(fg)'(x) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x).$

I have managed to write a proof for the statement using assumptions, $(fg)'(x) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$, $f(x) = x \implies f'(x) = 1$,  but I think it is necessary to use all 3 given. But I am not sure where should I use the last assumption $(f + g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x)$. My solution is below. I would really appreciate your help!

Base case: Let $n=1$
$$h(x)\mid_{n=1} = x^1 $$
$$h'(x)\mid_{n=1} = (1)x^{1-1} = 1 \implies \text{Statement holds true for base case}$$
Inductive Step: As statement holds for base case, assume by Principle of Mathematical Induction that statement holds true for the general case, $n=k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k>0$, that is
$$h(x) = x^k \implies h'(x)=kx^{k-1}$$
Now consider $ n=k+1:$
$$h(x)\mid_{n=(k+1)} = x^{k+1}$$
$$=(x^k)x$$
$$\implies h'(x) = (kx^{k-1})(x)+(x^k)(1) \text{ (by using assumptions given) } $$
$$= kx^{k-1+1} +x^k = kx^k +x^k$$
$$=(k+1)x^k \iff (k+1)x^{(k+1-1)} $$
$$\therefore{} \text{Statement is true for } n=k+1$$

Comment: Your proof is fine. Formal phrasing is maybe misplaced; you should put the "principle of mathematical induction" at the end, to actually make your conclusion, whereas as it stands you are putting a therefore without the explicit conclusion/justification. Now, if you were writing a maths paper, this would be fine as everyone would know what you meant. Indeed, papers often omit many steps and workings out. If you're in an exam however, a clearer structure is definitely good! The phrasing you meant to use was something like: "take the statement as true for $n\le k$ *by/as inductive hypothesis*"

Comment: To clarify, where you say "by using assumptions given", it is more common to say "by inductive hypothesis"

Comment: This is correct. You don’t need the final assumption. Just add a statement at the end saying the general case holds by induction.

Comment: And yes, the formula for derivative of a sum isn't useful for this.